# Replacing Pandas PivotTable Non-Null Result Cells With A Fixed String

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to convert a CSV that looks like the 1st example into one that looks like the 2nd example below.

I've been playing with Pandas and think I have the fundamentals working, but I can't seem to figure out **how to do one last transformation (from my placeholder value in the pivot to an actual English word)**.

In the code below, the piece I need help with is the comment that says "*I need to figure out something I can put here that will replace any non-null value found in the cells of column pivottally[c] with the string 'registered'*."

Note - if you suggest a more efficient way to go through the data than a for loop over a list of column names, feel free.  The for loop was just a way to test functionality as I use Pandas for the first time.

---

Input:

```
First  Last  Email      Program
john   doe   jd@me.com  BasketWeaving
jane   doe   dj@me.com  BasketWeaving
jane   doe   dj@me.com  Acrobatics
jane   doe   dj@me.com  BasketWeaving
mick   jag   mj@me.com  StageDiving
```

---

Desired output:

```
First  Last  Email      StatusBasketWeaving__c  StatusAcrobatics__c  StatusStageDiving__c
john   doe   jd@me.com  registered
jane   doe   dj@me.com  registered              registered
mick   jag   mj@me.com                                               registered
```

(there's actually one more column my code inserts, but it'd make this example too wide, so it's not shown here.)

---

Here's what I've written so far:

```
import pandas
import numpy

# Read in the First Name, Last Name, Email Address, & "Program Registered For" columns of a log file of registrations conducted that day.
tally = pandas.read_csv('tally.csv', names=['First', 'Last', 'Email', 'Program'])

# Rename the First Name & Last Name columns so that they're Salesforce Contact object field names
tally.rename(columns={'First':'FirstName', 'Last':'LastName'}, inplace=True)

# Create a concatenation of First, Last, & Email that can be used for later Excel-based VLOOKUP-ing Salesforce Contact Ids from a daily export of Id+Calculated_Lastname_Firstname_Email from Salesforce
tally['Calculated_Lastname_Firstname_Email__c'] = tally['LastName'] + tally['FirstName'] + tally['Email']

# Rename the values in Program so that they're ready to become field names for the Salesforce Contact object
tally['Program'] = 'Status' + tally['Program'] + '__c'

# Pivot the data by grouping on First+Last+Email+(Concatenated), listing the old registered-for-Program values as column headings, and putting
# a non-null value under that column heading if the person has any rows indicating that they registered for it.
pivottally = pandas.pivot_table(tally, rows=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Calculated_Lastname_Firstname_Email__c'], cols='Program', aggfunc=numpy.size)

# Grab a list of column names that have to do with the programs themselves (these are where we'll want to replace our non-null placeholder with 'Registered')
statuscolumns = [s for s in (list(pivottally.columns.values)) if s.startswith('Status')]

for c in statuscolumns:
    #pivottally.rename(columns={c:'Hi'+c}, inplace=True) # Just a test line to make sure my for loop worked.
    # I need to figure out something I can put here that will replace any non-null value found in the cells of column pivottally[c] with the string 'Registered'

print(pivottally.head())

#pivottally.to_csv('pivottally.csv')
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple selection can do the job. Building the columns list and iterating over it is useless, since all the columns are concerned. The other columns are in the index.

```
pivottally[pandas.notnull(pivottally)] = 'registered'
```

Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much, @romain-x - it worked!  For people visiting this page in the future, here's a note - I had to explicitly add "header = 0" to the "read_csv()" parameters to keep the 1st line of the CSV from being simultaneously treated as a header and as data to be processed.